# Get client user token from named pipe

Tags: c, security, winapi, pipe, uac

How to get user token for named pipe client from server side. I have found ImpersonateNamedPipeClient ,but I just want to query some information from it's token like sessionId.(I don't have access to client side code)
                                       Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `OpenThreadToken` after `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient` to check client account privileges, either by `GetTokenInformation`, or by `AccessCheck`.

Comment: That's good, but what SesdionID I'll have in that Token, from ClientProcess or from server process? I guess it's server one.

Comment: @BogdanMart No. `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient` allows server side to impersonate client side. You will get token with the client access rights and privileges.